# Is it OK to have a gas water heater in a bedroom closet?

Tags: water-heater, code-compliance, bedroom

I have a laundry room with a gas water heater in the closet.  I was thinking about taking out the washer and dryer and renting the laundry room as a bedroom because there is a bathroom next to the laundry room.  The water heater is vented to the outside and it is in a closet, would it be OK to use the room as a bedroom? I am in California.

Comment: Is there an air supply for the water heater (vented door, external air vent, etc)?  Does the bedroom contain an hvac supply vent?  Does the bedroom have a second exit (e.g. window, in addition to the door) in case of a fire?

Comment: Calf has tough laws about rental spaces. The room would have to have a legal sized egress window, and I bet you would need a permit or inspection of some type to be in compliance. Before you end up in "People's Court" or something similar, check with your local authorities about requirements.

Answer (score 1):

As stated, the room, itself, would have to meet codes for a bedroom (size, egress, etc.)

As for the water heater, it needs combustion air. If the room is smallish and making it a bedroom means it's going to be closed off, then you likely will need to convert the gas heater to either electric or to direct vent. The latter adds a blower that pulls in combustion air from outside. The con to that is that it may be noisy if in a closet.

Comment: A non-forced-draft direct vent unit such as the [A.O.Smith Promax GDV line](http://www.hotwater.com/water-heaters/residential/conventional/gas/promax/new-promax-direct-vent-gas-tank-water-heater-gdv-40/) (not an endorsement, just the unit I know of that does this) is an option for this situation -- same outside sourcing of combustion air, no blower needed.